# Создать словарь на основе двух списков

Tags: python, python-3.x, словари

Проблема заключается в том, чтобы создать новый словарь на основе данных массива целых чисел и другого словаря. Новый словарь должен отображать список городов, которых посетил коммивояжер.

Для данных `[2, 4, 5, 6, 3, 1, 2]` это должно выглядеть так `['Zhytomyr', 'Poltava', 'Chernihiv', 'Lviv', 'Vinnitsa', 'Kiev', 'Zhytomyr']`

Мой код:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([2, 4, 5, 6, 3, 1, 2])
items= {}
items = dict()
cities = {
    "Kyiv": 1,
    "Zhytomyr" : 2,
    "Vinnitsa" : 3,
    "Poltava" : 4,
    "Chernihiv" : 5,
    "Lviv" : 6,
    }
    
print(arr)    
dictkeys = list (cities.keys())
print("List of keys in Dictionary : ", dictkeys)
print(cities)

for i in arr:
    dictKey = cities.get(i)
    items[dictKey].append(i) 
      
dictkeys2 = list (items.keys())
print("List of keys in Dictionary : ", dictkeys2)
```

Результат кода должен быть таким:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня возникает ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как ee исправить?

Comment: Вопрос не понятен. Конкретизируйте проблему. Откуда берутся строки? Зачем Вы привели код. Не ясно, что вы хотите сделать

Comment: Метод словаря `get` возвращает `None`, когда ключ не найден в словаре. Вы берете числа из arr, пытаетесь по ключу-числу взять данные из словаря, где у вас ключи - строки (названия городов). Естественно по числовым ключам у вас ничего не находит.

Comment: @hedgehogues, в правилах сайта прямо рекомендуется приводить минимальный воспроизводимый пример, демонстрирующий проблему. Очевидно, поэтому код в вопросе.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Переверните словарь, и все станет просто

```
dictkeys = {y:x for x,y in cities.items()}
print(dictkeys)
# {1: 'Kyiv', 2: 'Zhytomyr', 3: 'Vinnitsa', 4: 'Poltava', 5: 'Chernihiv', 6: 'Lviv'}

dictkeys2 = [dictkeys.get(i) for i in arr ]
print("List of keys in Dictionary : ", dictkeys2)
# List of keys in Dictionary :  ['Zhytomyr', 'Poltava', 'Chernihiv', 'Lviv', 'Vinnitsa', 'Kyiv', 'Zhytomyr']
```

Comment: Спасибо, очень помогли *)